# How to ensure two different applications running on the same machine attach to the same starting address with shmat

Tags: linux, c++11, ipc, shared-memory

I am working on two completely separate applications that will need to use System V shared memory as a means of IPC. After reading [The Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/shmat), it seems like I will have to provide both applications with an address hint in order to guarantee that they point to the exact same memory location. I will be able to (almost) guarantee that they both have the same shmid, as described below. So I was wondering, 1. If NULL is passed as the second param and 0 as the third, will I be able to be 100% certain that the system will point both applications to the same starting location in memory if given the same shmid? And 2. If not, is there is a way to, at runtime, figure out what addresses the system is using for shared memory to make sure both applications use an address hint that won't cause the shmat to fail?

Example of code being used:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t dataBuffer[SHARED_MEM_BUFFER_SIZE]; //8 byte char array
} SharedData;

typedef struct
{
  int32_t dataIndex;
  SharedData data;
} SharedDataStructure;

bool initialize()
{
  //Parse JSON file for key gen file path and char
  auto keyGenFilePath = ...//Parsed file path
  auto keyGenChar = ...//Parsed char

  //Both applications will be reading the exact same json file, to ensure
  //they both receive the same key.
  key_t sharedMemKey = ftok(keyGenFilePath.c_str(), keyGenChar[0]);
  if (sharedMemKey == -1)
  {
    //Log error
    return false;
  }

  //m_shMemId is an int, m_params is a std::vector<SharedDataStructure>
  m_shMemId = shmget(sharedMemKey, m_params.size() * sizeof(SharedData), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
  if (m_shMemId == -1)
  {
    //Log error
    return false;
  }

  //m_attachedSharedMem is a SharedData pointer
  m_attachedSharedMem = (SharedData *)shmat(m_shMemId, NULL, 0);
  if (m_attachedSharedMem == (void *)-1)
  {
    //Log error
    return false;
  }

  //Zero out shared memory
  return true;
}
```

Also, please note that both applications will initialize their shared memory this way (Only one will zero the memory). This is also going on a very barebones system, so these two applications WILL be the only two applications using shared memory outside of the OS. Also, using POSIX shared memory is not an option, not because of system limitations, but due to other factors.

I apologize for not being able to provide a copy-paste compilable example, the application(s) need to be highly configurable to avoid having the change code in the future.